# How to change the Windows Search Index location using powershell?

Tags: search, powershell, automation, indexing, windows-search

The Default location for Windows Search index is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft`. In my case this location is on a SSD with limited space. Hence i want to move the index cache to a different drive with more of space. I know how to do this using GUI.

I wanted to find out how to do this using PowerShell? So i can automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this via the windows registry:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search" -Name "DataDirectory" -Value "X:\Microsoft\Search\Data\"
```